# My data var saves only my first input. How can I make my Var dynamic?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to make a Star Patter Generator. The most of the code works but I got one Problem. The data var saves the input from the field and pass the value to the child widget.

RootPage Widget

```
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  int data = 1;
  var list = [];

  void getData(int newNumb) {
    setState(() {
      data = newNumb;
    });
  }

  void getList(var newList) {
    setState(() {
      list = newList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar:
            CustomBarWidget(sendData: getData, data: data, getList: getList),
        body: StarTriangleWidget(data: data, list: list));
  }
}
```

CustomBar Widget

```
class CustomBarWidget extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  CustomBarWidget({super.key, this.sendData, this.getList, required this.data});

  int data;
  var sendData;
  var getList;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(70.0);

  @override
  State<CustomBarWidget> createState() => _CustomBarWidgetState();
}

class _CustomBarWidgetState extends State<CustomBarWidget> {
  late int _data = widget.data;
  late final _getList = widget.getList;
  final starList = [];

  void buildlist() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _data; i++) {
      starList.add(StarRow(index: 1));
    }
    debugPrint('$_data');

    _getList(starList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextfielWidget(onChange: (val) {
            widget.sendData(int.parse(val));
          }),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => {buildlist()},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              "Enter",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Textfiel Widget

```
class TextfielWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  void Function(String)? onChange;

  TextfielWidget({super.key, required this.onChange});

  @override
  State<TextfielWidget> createState() => _TextfielWidgetState();
}

class _TextfielWidgetState extends State<TextfielWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
        child: TextField(
            onChanged: widget.onChange,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Enter Number',
            )));
  }
}
```

StarTriangle Widget

```
class StarTriangleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  int data;

  StarTriangleWidget({super.key, required this.data, this.list});

  final list;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Center(child: StarRow(index: index + 1));
        });
  }
}
```

The Problem is after I type in a number and after that another number, the data value saves only the first number and don't save a new input number until I hot reload the app. I removed all final and const statements but It's not working.

That means if I type in 10 and click Enter, my Star Patter has 10 Rows. After that I type in 5 but it has also 10 Rows until I hotreload the app.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I find a Answer. I made my CustomBar Widget to an StatelessWidget.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).